# Button response position not changed after animation in Android version lower than 3.0

Tags: java, android, user-interface

#### Method

Using tweened view animation.

#### Expected Result

A button, placed on spot `A`, once on clicked, it moves rightward to spot `B`. Then I click that button on the spot `B`, it move leftward to spot `A`.

#### Problem

First clicking on spot `A`, the button did move to spot `B`. Then a click at spot `B` brings up no response, instead, it will respond always to clicking at spot `A`.

#### Main.java

```
package com.example.animationdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    boolean flagToggleButton = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (flagToggleButton == false) {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, R.anim.animation_move_right);
                    b.startAnimation(anim);
                    flagToggleButton = true;
                }
                else {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main.this, R.anim.animation_move_left);
                    b.startAnimation(anim);
                    flagToggleButton = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### anim_move_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="200%"
        android:startOffset="0" />
</set>
```

#### anim_move_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-200%"
        android:startOffset="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: This is how `TranslateAnimation` works, it didn't move the view to new position you have to set the layout params for your button so it actually does move to new position, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15943006/1939564

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thank you! You solved me problem. I've read your code and now it's working on my device too. Please move your comment to the answer part so that I can mark it as the solution of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `TranslateAnimation` works, it doesn't move the view to new position you have to set the `LayoutParams` for your **Button** so it actually does move to new position, check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943006/1939564) link for an example of how to move the view to new position

Answer (score 0):

After learning something about [fillEnabled, fillBefore, and fillAfter](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html?showComment=1340781197891), I've figured out a work-around, something similar to [Muhammad Babar's work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880375/1939564).

**res > anim > anim_view_move_rightward.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="80%"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="0" />

</set>
```